# Passing repository environment variables to reusable workflow in Github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have defined few env vars in repository `DEV/QA/PROD` and have set of variables i.e. a,b,c that I want to pass to the resuable workflow. How to achieve that?

I have tried like below but the variable values are not accessible in the called workflow.

According to GitHub Actions docs:

> To reuse variables in multiple workflows, set them at the organization, repository, or environment levels and reference them using the vars context. For more information see "Variables" and "Contexts."

but it doesn't seem to work.

```yaml
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      config-path: .github/labeler.yml
      deploy-a: ${{ vars.a}}
      deploy-b: ${{ vars.b }}
    secrets:
      envPAT: ${{ secrets.envPAT }}
```

In the target workflow, when I use `${{ inputs.deploy-a }}` it doesn't give any value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you configure those variables? Did you try to verify those by printing their values in a separate step? Please include this information in your question. Thanks!

Comment: yes, if i add another job use environment: DEV and then do echo ${{var.deploy-a}} , it prints fine , but in a reusable workflow i cannot use environment: tag , so not sure how to pass them

Comment: In your called workflow, you can specify the environment.

Comment: but the var values are not being reflected

Comment: Could you please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) with all the details? I'll try to reproduce it on my side.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution to it @wehelpdox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue myself, and was really struggling to find the cause of this.

What I discovered was that there was no way to set the environment for the workflow calling the reusable workflow. That means that if you have defined your environment variables for each environment (dev, production, etc), the variables will not be available by using the `vars` scope.

My solution was to send `environment` as parameter to the reusable workflow and the extract the variables using `vars` there. Not as pretty as I would have liked, but it works.

From my reusable workflow:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: string
        required: true
env:
  deploy-a: ${{ vars.a }}
  deploy-b: ${{ vars.b }}
jobs:
  do-something:
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

Then you can use `${{ env.deploy-a }}` in the remainder of the workflow.

Comment: You can also use simply `${{ vars.a }}` throughout the workflow to eliminate duplication.